# Were method cascades ever considered for C#?

Tags: c#

Smalltalk supports a syntax feature called "message cascades". [Cascades are being adopted](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m1-language-changes/#cascades) by the [Dart Programming language](http://www.dartlang.org/).

As far as I know, C# doesn't support this. Were they ever considered during the design of the language? Is it conceivable that they could appear in a future version of the language?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for [so]. This is not a discussion forum, nor a place for opinion or speculation.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Various members of the C# team are active on StackOverflow. They are in a position to answer this language design question authoritatively.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. It's a place for concrete answers to concrete questions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I ask a specific question in the second paragaph.

Comment: i think that in the C# there is already a good optimization done by the virtual machine, Smalltalk is a compiled language, at runtime they works differently.

Comment: That's not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.Net there is the `with` keyword which I believe is used for this purpose (correct me if I'm wrong on this), however in C# they decided that it can often hurt readability and left it out (good in my opinion).

Some short details can be found at the below link, however the link to the microsoft page is no longer working:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/11/why-doesn-t-c-have-vb-net-s-with-operator.aspx

Note: If anyone has the following link archived I would love to read it (as the link is not working):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/vcsharp/team/language/ask/withstatement/default.aspx